# Imported android-map-extensions version 2.0 now my R.java file is missing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-maps-extensions

Ok, so I wanted to add the clustering feature to my app. I imported the android-map-extensions to Eclipse and made reference to it in my apps properties and removed reference to the google-play-services, but when I imported android-map-entensions there were tons of errors in it, and now my R.java file for my project has disappeared!

In my project I now have errors under every R. in my MainActivity and have to add references to the R. in the androidmapextensions. i.e R.layout R.id etc etc What is going on?

If I cannot get this to work I will end up deleting my project and restoring it from a backup

Thanks

Comment: Remove R imports and clean your project.

Comment: You are Having issue within your res folder

Comment: @Nfear - I have done that but no joy. It seems to have turned out that I had cycle errors, and somehow managed to force my project to reference the android-map-extensions in a way that Eclipse didn't like

Comment: When using AME 2.0 or above also add google-play-services-lib (or keep it if you were already using it). Since 2.0 this library is decoupled from Google Play Services and you may use any version from 3.2.65 (the last working on Android API 8) or above.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. Since I have now implemented this, I have changed all my FragmentManagers to SupportFragmentManagers, but now my app doesn't load - LogCat says it cannot find MainActivity